# Large 30+ mil row table needing to use where IN clause

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

We have a table that contains, as of today, 30+ million rows of addresses. We have a field `status int` that is either 1 or 0. We need to be able to query the table `select count(*) from addresses where status = 1 AND zip IN (...)` I have created an index as `idx_area(status, zip)`

If I run a query as `where status = 1 AND zip = '12345'` it only takes milliseconds.
If I run a query as `where status = 1 AND zip IN (...)` it takes 5+ seconds.

Is there anything I can do to better optimize this query? I am worried that as we add more and more rows, it will get even slower. Also, some of our queries will have 40+ zips in the IN clause.

Comment: Please show the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for your two queries! Also, please provide the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE blah\G`.

Comment: to heloy you we mist see also the comand of the in clause and the crete tables from bith tables. you must use a inner join

Comment: What is the percentage of rows with status =1?

Comment: Dump the `IN` values into a temporary table and join it

Comment: Do you have any updates ?  I'm facing the similar problem with mysql !

Answer (score 4):

Is the list of zips in your `IN (...)` predicate really long? At my company we have had the problem since MySQL 5.7 that there's a cap on the memory the optimizer can use, according to the option range_optimizer_max_mem_size. If you have too many items in the list, the optimizer gives up, and decides to do a table-scan instead of use the index.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/range-optimization.html#range-optimization-memory-use

Our solution was to set this in the my.cnf:

```
range_optimizer_max_mem_size=0
```

It means there is no memory limit for the optimizer, so it's up to the developer to avoid a list so long that it causes memory faults. But it's more likely to use an index.

This has fixed the issue in every case where a long list was causing a table-scan.

Comment: Well, I get the slowness with just two. I'd expect it to be sub second with just two. There will be 40 or so when in production, so thanks for pointing this out. I will double what it is today, from 8mb to 16mb.